# Do OpenMP pragma directives need curly braces?

Tags: c, openmp

If I have an omp pragma directive in c that only applies to a single line, do I need curly braces?

For instance is:

```
#pragma omp atomic update
x += 1;
```

the same as:

```
#pragma omp atomic update
{
x += 1;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp121.bg.doc%2Fcompiler_ref%2Fprag_omp_atomic.html

The line after the #pragma omp atomic update takes either an expression_statement (one line) or a structured_block (bracketed block). So they should do the same thing.